# Push notification in blackberry using cordova with fcm (firebase) plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, blackberry

In cordova, I am developing hybrid app for android and blackberry10. For backend ,we are using firebase(fcm) plugin. For push notification it asks for device token in which android providing,

```
  FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token) {
}
```

But in case of Blackberry10, i cannot take device token, even i used to send device pin,

```
device.uuid //java script
```

its not working.can any one give me proper solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blackberry there is no uuid. We must need to register the app in

Visit https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_2/develop_a_push-enabled_app.html

you will get mail with token in 5 working days.